# find mutual connection between users in neo4j?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

find all users mutual connections in neo4j db

here is the solution
`MATCH (u1:Profile)-[r1]->(c:Profile), (u2:Profile)-[r2]->(c) WHERE u1 < u2 RETURN u1.name, u2.name, collect(c.name) as mutual_connections`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

MATCH (u1:Profile)-[r1]->(c:Profile), (u2:Profile)-[r2]->(c) WHERE u1 < u2 RETURN u1.name, u2.name, collect(c.name) as mutual_connections

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer or an update to the question? In the former case, please read [answer] and then [edit] this to improve it. In the latter case, please delete this and edit your question instead.